# getExportFields function in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I want to know that How I can customize getExportFields function in Sonata Admin extend Class.

My Problem is my class fields createdAt type is datetime but I want when admin download this class data then in CSV or XLS file createdAt format DATE, not a datetime.

I want show data in CSV or XLS file through join other tables.

I searched many times on google but nothing found.

This one I try for join but I am not success-

```
public function getExportFields()
{
$em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('ABC\FroBundle\Entity\Model');
$conn = $em->getConnection();
$query = "SELECT mp.id, mp.userModel, u.email, m.model_name
        FROM model_p mp
        LEFT JOIN user u ON mp.user_id = u.id
        LEFT JOIN m_model m ON mp.model_id = m.id limit 1";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $res){
    $reets = $res;
}
  $fieldsArray = $reets;
}
```

Any one know this type issue please help.

I asked this question on Github:- https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2221

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution by @Petr Slavicek can help:
Original question: [symfony2 - SonataAdminBundle Exporter issue with mapped entities - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479125/sonataadminbundle-exporter-issue-with-mapped-entities#21485426)

Try to use the Doctrine DateTime formatter on the object e.g.:

```
if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
    $value = $this->dateFormater->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ya it's working. you have any idea regarding :- How to show data in CSV or XLS file through other table If both table No mapping ?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand? Would you like to switch the export type (CSV or XLS) and then do different queries? Or, in addition, do you have non-entity tables you need to query?

Comment: Thanks for earliest response. Actual I have entity(A) and this entity(A) no relation to other entities. This entity have many field's like userId , productId etc..Ok When I Export this Entity (A) then In CSV or XLS file I got UserID and ProductId this is correct. But I want when I export Entity(A) then field's like productId get Product Name through Other Entity(Product) by Join. It is possible when I export ?

Comment: So Entity A has a product ID and there is another Datasource - an Entity B - named Product that e.g. has a name or a number. But A and B are not mapped to eachother? If both are Entities and handled via Doctrine ORM / ODM you can write custom SQL sure. I think it's best to post your Entities an gist.githubg.com to clearify your initial situation.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Named product number and Not mapped A nd B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64306/discussion-between-kunwar-siddharth-singh-and-webdevilopers).