# SonataAdminBundle Exporter issue with many to many

Tags: symfony, export, sonata-admin

currently I'm using sonata admin bundle to export a "order" data, how can I export the data with manytomany relationship? I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479125/sonataadminbundle-exporter-issue-with-mapped-entities), it helps a bit, but I still not sure how to get the data in many to many relationship.

Here is my code:
    public function getExportFields() {

```
    return [
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Order Number') => 'id', 
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('First Name') => 'customer.First_name',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Last Name') => 'customer.Last_name',
        ...]
```

Here is fine, but when I try to get 'OrderToProduct' or 'product.name' it failed or only output empty string. I spent to much time on this already, hope someone can give a clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't use product.name, because product is a collection.
Export action iterates through objects and get properties with path defined and tries to stringify them.

What you need to do is a workaround - define some method in Order class - i.e. getProductsAsString(), make it return string you need, and then add

```
$this->getTranslator()->trans('Products') => 'productsAsString'
```

But still - it will put whole string in single cell of xls, csv, xml you are trying to export.

Comment: In your codes mentioned:    $this->getTranslator()->trans('Products') => 'productsAsString', does 'productsAsString' refer to the method getProductsAsString() or just a variable? I'm not really sure how sonata work with its "path" things, I'm still trying to understand it..THX

Comment: Can I ask one more thing @tiriana, I got multiple items in 'products', if I want to export them out to csv file, can I make them one item in a line? Cause all the exports are in single row, it is hard to clarify the relationship between the item numbers and totals in one line, it better to split into different rows. Sorry for asking too more, but it seems not many people using this framework.THX

Comment: About second question: Well, there's always a way. But there is simple way to do that with Sonata built-in exporter, not while exporting Orders. You would need to be exporting OrderToProduct associations. But I think that such manner would require some custom export, so I wouldn't use this built-in one. You can write your own custom action to export what you need. And while you need csv not xls you don't even need to import some 3party libraries. Hope that'll be of any help

Comment: Thx @tiriana. I'll try the second by myself, but in the first one, I'm not sure what to code in the method getProductAsString(), cause I cant even get the data from this admin.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean, I missed understand you. I finally got my result, thx @tiriana.